# Render animation zooms in rendered video?

Tags: rendering

Haven't had this issue before, but for some reason now, **after rendering** my video, the bottom potion of my video goes missing.
For example, the view of the video when rendering seems to have zoomed in and so the chest up to the chin is cut off.
How do I fix this issue?
(I'm using Blender 2.83.5) Thank you.

[image][image]

Comment: First make sure that you are seeing the whole render screen by pressing the home key

Comment: The image you posted is very low resolution and hard to read.  Make screengrabs within blender https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHzGA.png.

Comment: I've completed an entire rendering of this video edit with this negative result.

Comment: I've unchecked the Render Region box, but nothing has changed.

Comment: It is hard to help if you don't respond to the comments. Did you press home in the rendered image to see the whole picture? Is theoriginal source video the same size as the render size (1920*1080)?

Comment: Just checked the size of the video and discovered that it is not 1920x1080, but much larger. Going to try changing it now. Thanks.

Comment: Just changed the resolution, with Frame All Fit and I think the issue has been resolved. I'm just waiting till the rendering has finished to confirm satisfaction. In the meantime, thanks so much for your help. I really wasn't expecting feedback so quickly and efficiently. You've been a great help!

Comment: please write an answer to your own question so that others can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the rendering was the same resolution size as the original footage and adding 'Frame All Fit' (on the Render page under 'view') dealt with this issue. Hope this helps :D